# How to get values of two different select elements and use them in a function

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, user-input, html-select

I have two different select elements. One where a user select their gender and the second where a user selects a place they live.

I have;

```html
<select class="selectGender" name="gender" id="styleSelect" required>
  <option value="">None</option>
  <option value="male">Male</option>
  <option value="female">Female</option>
</select>
```

and

```html
<select class="selectPlace" name="place" id="styleSelect" onchange="return checkGender()" required>
  <option name="dorm" value="">None</option>
  <option name="dorm" value="town" name="">Town</option>
  <option name="g" value="city">City</option>
</select>
```

What I want is that when a user selects male as gender and selects town from other select element, he should get an alert "not allowed".

Here's what I have done so far but I get nothing from this.

```js
function checkGender() {
  let gender = document.getElementsByName('gender');
  let place = document.getElementsByName('place');
  if (gender.value == "male" && place.value == "town") {
    alert("Not allowed");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have error on your html code check this

```
enter code here  

<select class="selectGender" name="gender"  id="styleSelect" required >
  <option value="">None</option>
    <option value="male">Male</option>
      <option value="female">Female</option>
     
</select>
      
 enter code here 
 
 <select class="selectPlace" name="place" id="styleSelect1" onchange="checkGender()" required>
    <option name="dorm" value="">None</option>
    <option name="dorm" value="town">Town</option>
    <option name="g" value="city">City</option>
    
</select>
    
    <script>
    function checkGender(){
      let gender=document.getElementsByName('gender')[0].value;
      let place=document.getElementsByName('place')[0].value;
      console.log(gender);
      console.log(place);
      if (gender=="male"&&place=="town") {
        alert("Not allowed");
      }
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of errors with your code:

- You can't have two or more elements with the same `id` but both of your `select`s have `id="styleSelect"`.
- You should add the `checkGender()` function to your first `select` too, as users not necessarily choose the second `select` last. Changing the first select should also fire the handler to check the values of the options.
- As others have mentioned, `getElementsByName` returns a NodeList collection of elements with the given name. It means, you need to grab the element at the zeroth index.

You can check the working code below by clicking on the "Run code snippet" button:

```js
function checkGender() {
  let gender = document.getElementsByName('gender')[0];
  let place = document.getElementsByName('place')[0];

  if (gender.value === "male" && place.value === "town") {
    alert("Not allowed");
  }
}
```

```html
<select name="gender" onchange="checkGender()" required>
  <option value="">None</option>
  <option value="male">Male</option>
  <option value="female">Female</option>
</select>
<select name="place" onchange="checkGender()" required>
  <option value="">None</option>
  <option value="town">Town</option>
  <option value="city">City</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try
document.getElementsByName('gender')[0].value

Comment: I get nothing from that bro

Comment: The thing is document.getElementsByName() returns collection of elements, as you have only one element with name gender you need to access it using index number as 0 from collection of elements. Thats why you need to access your element as  
 document.getElementsByName('gender')[0]. i hope it clears your doubt.